# while loop runs only one time

Tags: php, xampp

i'm trying to develop a trading application, i wrote this `PHP` script that's supposed to execute the buy and sell orders, it's scheduled to run every 5 minutes and execute all the orders in the orders table that are pending(status = 1).
the problem is that only one order is executed at a time. this is the script:

```
public function execute_order(){
    $which_sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status_id = 1 AND price = (SELECT max(price) FROM orders WHERE status_id = 1)";
    $which_result = $this->connection ->query($which_sql);
    if($which_result->num_rows>0){
        while($row=$which_result->fetch_assoc()){
            $which=$row["order_type_id"];
            $ord_id = $row["ord_id"];
            echo "order type id= ".$which."\r\n";
            $maxprice = $row["price"];
            $volume = $row["vol"];
            $ord_id= $row["ord_id"];
            $comp = $row["comp"];
            $sh_id = $row["sh_id"];
            echo "price =". $maxprice."\r\n";
            echo "volume= ".$volume."\r\n";
            echo "order id = ".$ord_id."\r\n";
            echo "comp = ".$comp."\r\n";
            echo "sh_id= ".$sh_id."\r\n";

            //start of the switch phrase
            switch ($which){
                //SELL ORDER
                case 1:
                    //the update query
                    $update_sql = "UPDATE orders SET status_id = 2 WHERE ord_id = $ord_id";
                    //update execution
                    if ($this -> connection->query($update_sql) === TRUE){
                        echo "1. SUCCESSFULL SELL UPDATE \r\n";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "ERROR SELL UPDATE: " . $this -> connection->error."\r\n";
                    }
                    //THE INSERT QUERY
                    $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO trades(tr_vol,tr_price, tr_ord_id) VALUES ('$volume','$maxprice','$ord_id')";
                    //THE INSERT EXECUTION
                    if($this->connection->query($insert_sql)==TRUE){
                        echo "2.SUCCESSFULL SELL INSERTION \r\n";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "ERROR SELL INSERTION: ".$this -> connection->error."\r\n";
                    }
                    //ADDITION QUERY
                    $add_sql = "UPDATE market_table SET volume = (volume+$volume) WHERE e_name LIKE '$comp'";
                    //ADDITION EXECUTION
                    if($this -> connection->query($add_sql)==TRUE){
                        echo "3. SUCCESSFULL SELL ADDITION \r\n";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "ERROR SELL ADDITION: ".$this -> connection->error."\r\n";
                    }
                    //PAYMENT QUERY
                    $total= ($maxprice*$volume);
                    $pay_sql= "UPDATE sh_credit SET credit = (credit+$total) WHERE sh_id = $sh_id";
                    //PAYMENT EXECUTION
                    if($this ->connection ->query($pay_sql)==TRUE){
                        echo"4. SUCCESSFULL SELL PAYMENT \r\n";
                        echo"________________________________________________________________\r\n";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "ERROR SELL PAYMENT: ".$this -> connection->error."\r\n";
                    }



                //BUY ORDER
                case 2:
                    //check if there are stocks available for the order to be executed
                    $check_sql= "SELECT volume FROM market_table WHERE lower(e_name) LIKE '$comp'";
                    echo "*********VOLUME CHECK POINT******* \r\n";
                    $check_result = $this -> connection->query($check_sql);
                    if($check_result->num_rows > 0){
                        if($check_row= $check_result->fetch_assoc()){
                            $check_vol=$check_row["volume"];
                            echo "remaining volume= ".$check_vol."\r\n";

                            //execute the order when stocks are available
                            if($check_vol>0){
                                $total= ($maxprice*$volume);
                                //check if shareholder has enough credit
                                $check_credit_sql="SELECT credit FROM sh_credit WHERE sh_id = $sh_id";
                                $check_credit_result = $this->connection->query($check_credit_sql);
                                if ($check_credit_row=$check_credit_result->fetch_assoc()){
                                    $check_credit=$check_credit_row["credit"];
                                }
                                //execute the order when credit is enough
                                if ($check_credit >0){
                                    //charging query
                                    $charge_sql= "UPDATE sh_credit SET credit = (credit-$total) WHERE sh_id = $sh_id";
                                    //charge execution
                                    if($this ->connection ->query($charge_sql)==TRUE){
                                        echo"4. SUCCESSFULL BUY CHARGING \r\n";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo "ERROR BUY CHARGING: ".$this -> connection->error."\r\n";
                                    }
                                    //the update query: update order's status
                                    $update_sql = "UPDATE orders SET status_id = 2 WHERE ord_id = $ord_id";
                                    //update execution
                                    if ($this -> connection->query($update_sql) === TRUE) {
                                        echo "1. SUCCESSFULL BUY UPDATE \r\n";
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        echo "ERROR BUY UPDATE: " . $this -> connection->error."\r\n";
                                    }   
                                    //insert query: insert into trades table the executed order
                                    $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO trades(tr_vol,tr_price, tr_ord_id) VALUES ('$volume','$maxprice','$ord_id')";
                                    //insert execution
                                    if($this -> connection->query($insert_sql) == TRUE){
                                        echo "2. SUCCESSFULL BUY INSERTION\r\n";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo "ERROR BUY INSERTION: ".$this -> connection->error."\r\n";
                                    }
                                    //substraction the volume query
                                    $sub_sql = "UPDATE market_table SET volume = (volume-$volume) WHERE e_name LIKE '$comp'";
                                    //sub execution
                                    if($this -> connection->query($sub_sql)==TRUE){
                                        echo "3. SUCCESSFULL BUY SUBSTRACTION \r\n";
                                        echo"________________________________________________________________ \r\n";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo "ERROR BUY SUBSTRACTING: ".$this -> connection->error."\r\n";
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo"shareholder doesn't have enough credit \r\n";
                                    //cancel query
                                    $cancel_sql="UPDATE orders SET status_id = 3 WHERE ord_id = $ord_id";
                                    //cancel execution
                                    if($this -> connection->query($cancel_sql)==TRUE){
                                        echo"1. ORDER CANCELED SUCCESSFULLY \r\n";
                                        echo "________________________________________________________________ \r\n";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo"ERROR CANCELING ORDER WHEN CREDIT ISN'T ENOUGH \r\n";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                echo "available stocks aren't enough \r\n";
                                //cancel query
                                $cancel_sql="UPDATE orders SET status_id = 3 WHERE ord_id = $ord_id";
                                //cancel execution
                                if($this -> connection->query($cancel_sql)==TRUE){
                                    echo"1. ORDER CANCELED BECAUSE STOCKS ARE ENOUGH \r\n";
                                    echo"________________________________________________________________ \r\n";
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo"ERROR CANCELING ORDER WHEN STOCKS AREN'T ENOUGH \r\n";
                                }   
                            }
                        }       
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}
```

Comment: and how many results you have when executing ```SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status_id = 1 AND price = (SELECT max(price) FROM orders WHERE status_id = 1)``` on sql server?

Comment: "`WHERE status_id = 1`" are you sure your result has not only 1 row ?

Comment: please run your query on phpmydmin and confirm it having more than one record.

Comment: yeah it only returns one record,gonna try to modify it, can you suggest me another way to execute the orders?? it's for a school project

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add:

```
break;
```

at the end of each case in the switch statment.

Comment: That might not solve your current problem, but you do need the break, unless you want to execute all cases.